# how to mock a object in method

Tags: java, mockito

I want to mock response object here when I call `getHSMDecryptedData` method from my test method.

```
private String getHSMDecryptedData(String keysetName, int groupIndex,
                                   String ksn, String encryptedData) {
    String decryptedData = null;
    try {
        DecryptData decrypt = new DecryptData();
        decrypt.setKeySet(keysetName);
        decrypt.setKsnDescriptor("906");
        decrypt.setKsn(ksn);
        decrypt.setKeyType(HSMKeyTypeDataModel.TYPE_BDK);
        decrypt.setEncryptionMode(HSMEncryptionMode.CBC);
        decrypt.setInputFormat(HSMDataFormat.HEX_ENCODED_BINARY);
        decrypt.setOutputFormat(HSMDataFormat.HEX_ENCODED_BINARY);
        decrypt.setMessage(encryptedData);

        // sending M2 command to HSM for decryption of encrypted data coming from CP
        DecryptDataResponse response = (DecryptDataResponse) HSMService.getInstance().processRequest(decrypt);

        System.out.println(response+"***************reponse");
        if (response != null && response.getResponseCode() == HSMResponseCodes.APPROVED) {
            decryptedData = response.getDecryptedMessage();
            TraceLog.Info(getClass(),
                "Message decrypted[" + decryptedData + "], original input[" + encryptedData + "], replacing original encrypted data!");
            if (decryptedData == null) {
            //  throw new FirstadatException("Unable to get the decrypted Data from HSM ");
            }
        }//FirstadatException
```

This is my test method:

```
HsmDataDecrypt hsmDataDecrypt = new HsmDataDecrypt();
    try {
        DecryptDataResponse response=mock(DecryptDataResponse.class);
        //response.
        Method method = hsmDataDecrypt.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getHSMDecryptedData", String.class,int.class,String.class,String.class);
```

Comment: You will probably find that PowerMock could solve your problem, since it allows you to mock static method calls. **Don't!** It's a bad solution for a problem you only have because your code is bad. Listen to Timothy, dependency injection will solve your problem and clean up your code nicely, while PowerMock will only allow you to hide the true problem.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> DecryptDataResponse response = (DecryptDataResponse) HSMService.getInstance().processRequest(decrypt);
> ```

You access the `HSMService` object via the *Java Singleton Pattern*. This kind of singletons are basically *global variables* which software developers consider being evil  since the late 80s...

You better *inject* the  `HSMService` object preferably as constructor parameter or any other *dependency injection* technique. 
In that case you can replace the `HSMService` object  with a mock which in turn returns a mock of the `DecryptDataResponse` class on call of the `processRequest` method.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion , i have made changes accordingly by create a constructor that injecting the HSMService object , now its mocking the response. thanks.